# Synonym for "utilize" that means "to use without waste"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for *utilize* that sounds less dry and emphasizes that nothing is being wasted.

"The program utilized all the supercomputer's resources."

Ideally, this word would make the word "all" redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options are *exploit* and *harness*:

> **exploit** <sup>[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1245657#m_en_us1245657)</sup>
>   make full use of and derive benefit from (a resource):
>   *500 companies sprang up to exploit this new technology*
>
> **harness**  <sup>[Macmillan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harness?show=1&t=1301765714)</sup>
>    utilize:
>   *harness the computer's potential*

Both words, especially *exploit*, fit your bill:

> The program exploited/harnessed the supercomputer's resources.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with ***exhaust*** or ***deplete***.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *used up*, *consumed*, *finished*, *spent*, *depleted*, *empty*, *drained*.